# Techniques for parsing code blocks without curly braces

Tags: c#, parsing, compiler-construction, interpreter

I'm writing a simple parser/interpreter in C# from scratch (no third-party libraries). It compiles to bytecode and then I have class that runs the bytecode. I'm getting close to wrapping it up. I've just implemented `while` and `for` loops and am working on `if`|`else if`|`else` blocks.

As it stands, my parser requires all of these structures to use curly braces. I'd like to make it more C-like and have the curly braces be optional when the block contains just a single statement. This is giving me trouble.

```
if (condition)
{
    // Make curly braces optional when there is just one statement here
}
```

The problem is tracking state. How does the parser know when a block without curly braces has ended. One approach would be to check if there is a block without braces in effect after each and every statement. However, there are a lot of different scenarios that would constitute a statement and so those checks would need to be in a number of places. That feels a little brittle to me.

I'm just wondering if anyone has done this and knows of any slick tricks for tracking when a code block ends when there are no curly braces.

Comment: What kind of parser have you implemented? What does your grammar look like for statements and statement blocks?

Comment: @IanMercer: I just have a lexer that breaks the source into tokens and then a parser that figures out the bytecode from the context. I wasn't following any special techniques. The language is somewhat C-like, although that is likely to change.

Comment: @IanMercer: In fact, I would probably change the language if it made it easier to deal with this issue.

Comment: Could you give some examples where it is difficult to tell when a block ends?

Comment: @JimW: In every instance. As I tried to explain, it would mean I'd need to do a test after each and every statement, and not all statements are processed in the same place. So this means adding checks all around the code. Any approach like that is brittle because you could miss a spot or forget to add one when you change the code. I was just wondering if anyone knew of a slicker approach.

Comment: I guess I don't understand - it's unclear to me why you wouldn't know when you've read a statement.  But I've never attempted to write a compiler, though it is interesting.

Comment: @JimW: Well, it's not like sequential lines of code that match the number of statements I'm reading. I have a loop that diverts off to different methods depending on the statements I'm parsing. For example, I call a method to parse `for` statements. So it's not quite that simple. I need state information that says I have a code block with no braces in effect. I guess it comes down to where you're going to examine that state information in your code. As I indicated, you would need to do it in a number of different places.

Comment: Are you doing recursive descent parsing?

Comment: @JohanP: Sorry, I have been reading about parsers but don't know enough about that technique. But I'm not using recursion so I wouldn't think so. I could probably still change the approach I take to parsing if it would somehow address the issue.

Comment: Your grammar should look like this: `statement = block | if ( expr) statement else statement | ...`, where `block` is a block of statements in curly braces.

Comment: I have a 99.9% delimiter-less grammar implemented. The 0.1% exception is when you want to have a block of expressions, you will always need a delimiter of some kind to indicate you are at the end of a block.

Comment: @FrankC.: C, C++ and C# allow blocks without delimiters. And now my code supports that too.

Comment: @JonathanWood - I'm was just referring to a 'block' of statements. Your comment below about the 4 statements was the impetus. I originally thought that was the question but re-reading it I see I was wrong..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look into [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). It makes creating parsers a lot easier. Lets assume you have grammar looking like this:

```
statement
   : 'if' paren_expr ['{'] statement ['}'] 

paren_expr
   : '(' expr ')'
```

then using recursive descent you can do something like:

```
public void Statement()
{
    if(curToken == Token.If)
    {
       Eat(Token.If); // Eat is convenience method that moves token pointer on
       if(curToken == Token.LParen)
       {
          Eat(Token.LParen)
          ParenExpr();
          Eat(Token.RParen);
       }
       if(curToken == Token.LBrace) // this will signify a block of statements
       {   
          Eat(Token.LBrace);
          while(curToken != Token.RBrace)
             Statement();
          Eat(Token.RBrace);
       }
       else
          Statement();              
    }
}

public void ParenExpr()
{
   // do other token checks
}
```

doing this for all of your non terminals, you can easily build up an AST and from that, you can generate your bytecode.

Comment: So, is the point of this that `Statement()` would be recursive by calling itself again if the statement called for it? I did think about calling a routine to process one statement, but of course that statement could be anything, including other `if` statements. So a lot could happen. But if `Statement()` is recursive then I suppose that would be okay.

Comment: BTW, the code you posted doesn't seem like it would work if the block had braces and more than one statement. How would that work?

Comment: I'm not following you? Are you saying it wouldn't parse `if(condition){ if(condition2) doSomething(); if(condition3) doSometingElse()}`? It would parse that.

Comment: No, I'm saying it wouldn't parse if there were, say, four statements between the braces. You call `Statement()` once. How would it handle that?

Comment: Well, you have to code in the rest of the method, that will just deal with `if`, it also wouldn't deal with `while` either because it is a simple example of your `if` problem

Comment: I'm trying to understand the goal here. If the `if` statement is followed by curly braces, and within the curly braces there are four statements, I don't see how this would work? You only call `Statement()` once. How would `Statement()` know when to return?

Comment: Give me an example of a statement you want then I can add it to my example

Comment: Am I really being that unclear? Four statements within the curly braces: `if (condition) { statement1(); statement2(); statement3(); statement4(); }`. Your code only calls `Statement()` once. How does it know to execute four statements?

Comment: It's recursive. So right now, we have only handled the `if` statement. So if your `statement(1)` `statement2()` `statement3()` `statement4()` were ALL `if` statements, then it would parse it. If you need an assign statement, i.e. `x = 4`, then you need to go add it in your `Statement` function.  `if(curToken == Token.Identifer) // do your assignment logic`. You need to handle all of the statement cases. I can't make this any clearer.

Comment: Yes, you already explained that. It couldn't be more clear that your code only handles `if` statements, and that support for other statements would need to be added. What I don't get is how `Statement()`, which your code only calls once, would know to execute four statements (regardless of what those statements are). I don't see a loop in `Statement()`, so it would appear to execute only one statement. I don't understand how `Statement()` knows how to execute four statements and then return.

Comment: if checks the current token, `curToken`, a global variable what your next token is. The `Eat` function moves the pointer on and sets your `curToken`.

Comment: I get that. But it doesn't at all explain how it knows to execute four statements and then return. There is no loop in `Statement()`. It will therefore execute a single statement and return. At which time your `if` handler will expect the closing parenthesis. The remaining three statements have not been executed. I'm missing a key feature of this approach. But perhaps we're just not going to be able to discuss it.

Comment: @JonathanWood I have updated my answer, you were right, it needed a `while` when a `{` is encountered as this signifies a block of statements.

Comment: While changes are needed to the structure of what you posted, I've backed up my existing code and am going to try to refactor to employ your general concepts. A few things might be harder, but it does simplify some of the issues I'm struggling with. Thanks.